# iOS finger print scan restriction from apple

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have login screen with finger print scan functionality, Is there any restriction or condition to use this functionality for development

Answer (score 2):

Local Authentication Framework provides `canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` and `evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` for Touch ID.

`evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics` is used to check if the user could authenticate successfully or not. This would only check if the user is authenticated with any of the users enrolled with Touch ID on the device. What you do not get is the actual data of the finger print scan - that is the restriction as far as I can see as a developer.

In terms of app store submission, the documentation clearly mentions

> "The localized string you present to the user should provide a clear
>   reason for why you are requesting they authenticate themselves, and
>   what action you will be taking based on that authentication."

Comment: I want to know is there any explanation required while submitting app to appstrore?

Comment: wouldn't have thought so. As long as you are doing it for a valid reason i.e. to protect user data. Pretty pointless just arbitrarily doing it anyway ...

Comment: The only thing that I saw in the documentation was "The localized string you present to the user should provide a clear reason for why you are requesting they authenticate themselves, and what action you will be taking based on that authentication."  I guess that's one thing to consider.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this.